# Can i just install ubuntu on a HP DV2000 and everything will work?

Tags: installation, hp

I would love to start using ubuntu and ubuntu only. I have a HP DV2000, that i was hoping could run the latest version. Can i just download ubuntu, burn ISO and install it as my main OS and everything will work 'out of the box' or will i need to work on it ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer relies on you.Better run the live system and check everything works or not.Up on booting,you can select either to `try Ubuntu` or to `install it`.Try it first from the live media and decide yourself,is it make any better to you or not.All the best and enjoy Ubuntu.

Download from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32).

Installation instructions are [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop).